# For loop + Booleans

Tags: python

Given this code:

```
nums = [1,2,3]

def test1(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if i == 1:
            return True
    return False

test1(nums)
```

The result is True even though after the for loop there is a return False. What am I missing?

Comment: The return statement terminates the function call.

Comment: Oh that makes sense thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, is this a school exercise?

Comment: No, just me doing online challenges trying to learn.

Comment: Whicheven return statement is executed first, that value will be returned to the caller and the function will be terminated!